# How do I store a "Size" value of a part in a variable?

Tags: variables, lua, size, roblox

I am trying to figure out how to store Size of a part in a variable.

This is my script:

```
while wait() do 
    local Intval = game.ReplicatedStorage.SizeNumb.Value
    script.Parent.Size = Intval
end
```

The output which I recieve is

```
Workspace.Part.Script:12: bad argument #3 to 'Size' (Vector3 expected, got number)
```

Comment: Isn't the error saying that `Size` needs to be a `Vector3`, but `Intval` is just a number?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for 'Part.Size'. There's a code example on how to change the Size property : https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/BasePart/Size

Comment: Thanks you for the link @Kylaaa

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes but I didn't know how to store them tho. I am new to Lua and this problem was pretty confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a Vector3 value like so:

```
script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt!